# Is it possible to key out green screen from a video in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, chromakey

Long story short, I'm making a game over screen for my 2D unity game. Animated it in Da Vinci with a green screen in the back of everything so that I can key it out.

Question is, can it be made transparent in Unity?

To add, my original plan was to create a 'freeze frame' after the character dies, and then the game over screen will pop up overlayed above the freeze frame which is below the last level scene where the freeze frame took place.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of animation this is, but you can probably try to make a shader for it, which reads the texture color for a pixel and do whatever you want with it. If green, make transparent, if not, render as is.

You could also try ShaderGraph. Here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nbvqi8cfnrc) of a RawImage shader using the texture provided, in ShaderGraph.